# How can I store a Date object in SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, date, sharedpreferences

I need to put the date object in shared preferences editor.

What datatype to convert it into for storing in shared preferences? Normally we write 
`prefEditor.putString("Idetails1", Idetails1);` for string and elements.

How do I do that? Can I use this for date object too?

```
private EditText pDisplayDate;
private ImageView pPickDate;
private int pYear;
private int pMonth;
private int pDay;
/** This integer will uniquely define the dialog to be used for displaying date picker.*/
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

Date date;

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pDateSetListener =
new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
    int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
       pYear = year;
       pMonth = monthOfYear;
       pDay = dayOfMonth;
       updateDisplay();
       displayToast();
    }
};

private void updateDisplay() {
    pDisplayDate.setText(
       new StringBuilder()
       // Month is 0 based so add 1
       .append(pMonth + 1).append("/")
       .append(pDay).append("/")
       .append(pYear).append(" ")
    );
}

private void displayToast() {
    Toast.makeText(this, 
        new StringBuilder()
        .append("Date choosen is ")
        .append(pDisplayDate.getText()),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: of course it is possible. where do you want to save and load the information?

Comment: @StefanBeike i need to store it in sqlite and later upload it to the server...currently i only need to save it in database.

Comment: Database has nothing to do with SharedPreferences...

Comment: ya i know but i am storing it in databse in this way `prefEditor.putString("Idetails1", Idetails1);ArrayList<String> dbvalues = new ArrayList<String>();
   
   dbvalues.add(settings.getString("Firt_Name", "")); WayDataBase way = new WayDataBase(ProfilePage3.this);
   way.insertPeopleValues(dbvalues);`

Answer (score 6):

> can i use this for date object too??

The simpliest way i think you can use is convert `Date` to its String representation. Then you can simply convert it back to Date object using some date formatter.

```
String dateString = date.toString();
SharedPreferences p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(<context>);
p.edit().putString("date", dateString).commit();
```

### Update:

Also how @MCeley pointed out, you can also convert `Date` to long and put its long value:

```
long dateTime = date.getTime();
SharedPreferences p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(<context>);
p.edit().putLong("date", dateTime).commit();
```

Comment: Long has always been my preference since it takes up less space and doesn't lock you into using one date string format.  It also doesn't require you use a date formatter to convert back to a date.

Comment: @MCeley man now i think that long is better, too. you don't need date formatter then also and how you mentioned, it takes less place - and this is important especially in mobile development where each byte of memory is important.

Comment: wii the string get stored in the database if the datatype in the database is Date???

Comment: @shiv db is something differenet as SP. i think that sqlite does not support date format, only string so you can convert date to string and   save to db.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Calendar object to set the date whenever it change or retrieve from the Preference object its easy to use.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); // use system date on first time for initialization.

long millis= pref.getLong("date",c.getTimeInMillis()); // retrieve date from Preference object in long format

c.setTimeInMillis(millis); // now set in calendar and then use it

//on date change set the year, month and day into calendar to and then stored in preference

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                pYear = year;
                pMonth = monthOfYear;
                pDay = dayOfMonth;
                c.set(pYear , pMonth , pDay ); // set into the calendar and when need to save in preference do this
                Editor edit = pref.editor();
                edit.put("date",c.getTimeInMillis());
                edit.commit();
                updateDisplay();
                displayToast();
            }
        };
```